# Downsampling a multivariate empirical distribution

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, bootstrap, simulation, distance

By means of stochastic simulation I can create a large (N = a few mio, say) iid sample of a complex multivariate distribution. For several reasons, lack of computational resources among them, I would like to create a smaller (N = a few thousands) sample of the same distribution.

Of course a completely straightforward approach is to choose just a suitably small number of scenarios from the large sample. But obviously I would like to retain in the small sample as much "information" as possible from the large sample and I would like to do better than this "naive" approach.

### General questions

1) Are there generic ways to accomplish this? With generic I mean methods which do not depend on properties of the specific distribution or samples.

2) What are suitable similarity or quality measures, to decide whether the small sample is "close to" or "represents well" the larger sample?

3) Does this problem has a generally accepted name, which I could use to sift through the literature?

### Specific approach

One hands-on approach to tackle this problem is to define a target statistics deemed important for the problem. Then the difference of the target statistics between large and small sample is used as a quality criteria. To find an optimal small sample, I would resample the large sample, until I find a sub-sample with a suitably small (squared) difference to the full sample.

1) Is this method any good in a statistical sense (e.g. unbiased, consistent, efficient, ...)?

2) What would it need to estimate the number of resampling trials required to achieve a certain approximation quality as measured by the (squared) difference in target statistics?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer now, but check out "herding": [first paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.149.8226&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [extension to continuous spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3472) known as _kernel herding_, which it [turns out](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1664) is closely related to Bayesian quadrature; see also [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02681).

Comment: I had a closer look at the papers. Indeed, this is pertinent and interesting information! You do not happen to know about papers which are concerned with practical aspects? The choice of Kernel and parameters such as bandwidth seem to be critical here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know of any practical papers using herding, though you might be able to find some by digging through Google Scholar. It's definitely important, but it depends a lot on what kinds of functions you want to apply to the sample. A usually-reasonable-enough default is to use an exponentiated quadratic (aka Gaussian / square-exponential) kernel, with bandwidth set to the median distance among your data sample.

Comment: I also don't know how well the algorithm will scale to a few million samples; the algorithm in (8) of [the kernel herding paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.3472.pdf) requires computing the full kernel matrix. You could look into kernel approximations like random Fourier features or Nyström, and only greedily choose the best of a smaller set of (random?) candidate points.